# Doubt in Step I of Proof of Riesz Representation Theorem (Rudin's RCA)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I have some questions regarding step I of Rudin's proof of Riesz Representation Theorem (Real and Complex Analysis). I have included what I've tried. Please scroll down for the attached reference.

---

**Question 1:** How does (5) follow from (6)?

$g \prec V_1\cup V_2$ tells us $\Lambda g \le \mu(V_1\cup V_2)$. If I put $g = \chi_{(V_1\cup V_2)}$ in (6), I get (5) - but is this okay to do?

**Question 2:** Why is $\mu(V) \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i) + \epsilon$ in the last line?

I was only able to see that if $f\prec V$ (which means $0\le f\le 1$, $f\in C_c(X)$, and $\text{supp}(f) \subset V$), $$\Lambda f = \int_X f\ d\mu = \int_{\text{supp}(f)} f\ d\mu \le \int_{\text{supp}(f)} 1\ d\mu \le \int_V 1\ d\mu = \mu(V)$$ which doesn't really help.

> [image]
> [image]

Comment: For your second question note that $$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\mu (V_i )}  < \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {(\mu (E_i ) + 2^{ - i} \varepsilon )}  =\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\mu (E_i )}  + \varepsilon \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {2^{ - i} }  < \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {\mu (E_i )}  + \varepsilon \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {2^{ - i} }  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {\mu (E_i )}  + \varepsilon .
$$

Comment: Thank you, that clears Q2 up.

Comment: And you answered question 1. Indeed choose $g$ to be the characteristic function of the union set.

Comment: Okay, amazing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To collect @Gary's comments into an answer:

---

Q1. $g = \chi_{V_1\cup V_2}$ works, since the support of $g$ is contained in $V_1\cup V_2$, $0 \le g \le 1$, and $$\Lambda g = \int_X g\ d\mu = \mu(V_1\cup V_2)$$

---

Q2.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(V_i) < \sum_{i=1}^n (\mu(E_i) + \epsilon/2^i) < \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \epsilon/2^i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i) + \epsilon$$
Taking limits as $n\to\infty$, we get $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(V_i) \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu(E_i) + \epsilon$$
and by countable subadditivity we have $$\mu(V) \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(V_i)$$ which gives the result.